# Does brain size matters for the intelligence of an organism?

Tags: neuroscience

It was shown in a local TV show that larger the brain, larger the intelligence of that organism.

Does that mean if more number of neurons present in the brain canit helps in improving the intelligence of that organism?

Comment: does [this answers](https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/57782/9943) your question?